# SQL to find a common element in 2 lists

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join, relational-division

I run into this situation from time to time, where I want to take a list of things and see if any of them exist in another list.

If you have a single number, it's simple enough to use a where clause to say something like:

```
where topic_id IN (select topic_id from articles where article_id = 101)
```

But what if, say, I have a user who's selected a list of categories they're interested in (1,2,7,25,66), and I want to pull the most recent 15 articles that fall under any of those topics, and a given article can belong to 1 or more topics? It doesn't work to say:

```
where (select topic_id from articles) IN (1,2,7,25,66)
order by topic_date desc
```

It's possible to loop over the right list in a scripting language, doing a separate query for 1,2,7,25, and 66, but that could get very inefficient if it were a longer list. Is there a relatively efficient way to do something like this in a single SQL query?

sample data:

articles

```
article_id     Title                         Text
1              Today's IC flavor             Today's IC will be strawberry.    
2              Looking Sunny                 Today's going to be hot!
3              Good day to fly               No flights have been delayed today, because the weather is great!
4              Game on!                      There will be an epic baseball game today
5              Hockey too?                   There will be a hockey game today, indoors.
6              Special Aftergame Event       In Tokyo, there will be an ice cream party after the baseball game. Woot!
```

topics

```
topic_id       topic_name
1              Food
2              Travel
3              Weather
4              sports
```

link_article_topic

```
article_id        topic_id
1                 1
2                 3
3                 2
3                 3
4                 4
5                 4
6                 1
6                 2
6                 4
```

Notice that some articles have records for more than 1 topic in link_article_topic. This is simplified - my real world case has a much more extensive list of topics and articles, and my real world user has a much longer list of preferred topics, but it's the same concept.

So say my user has preset their desired topics to (2,4), or Travel and Sports. Say also that the articles table has a date field for when the article was published. I want to get the 3 most recent articles, in descending date order, that belong to the Travel and Sports topics.

In my real-world case, I tried a query using EXISTS similar to below, but it timed out. Please correct me if I have the syntax wrong, but I believe the "a." is necessary for the WHERE in that EXISTS statement:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.Title, a.Text
FROM Articles a
WHERE a.extraColumn1 IN (list)
    AND a.extraColumn2 IN (anotherList)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT article_id from link_article_topic
                 WHERE article_id = a.article_ID
                   AND topic_ID IN (2,4))
    ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Comment: How about `ìntersect` (see <https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html)?

Comment: *see if any of them exist* sound like you need to use `exists` - some sample data and expected results would help greatly.

Comment: What's the specific database? Also, please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Okay, I edited the original article to include some sample data and more details on what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Use an inner join rather than IN  perhaps

Comment: `IN (list)` what is list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a mapping table to associate topics with articles (an excellent choice) you can use an INNER JOIN and a DISTINCT phase to remove duplicates

EDIT NOTE: This has been re-written to target MySQL at OP's request, here is a link to an online MySQL interpreter with the below code snippet
https://extendsclass.com/mysql/825408f

```
/*BEGIN sample data*/
with cteTopics as (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (VALUES ROW(1, 'Art'), ROW(2, 'Music'), ROW(3, 'Poetry')
            , ROW(4, 'Literature'), ROW(5, 'Math'), ROW(6, 'Physics')
            , ROW(7, 'Photography'), ROW(8, 'News'), ROW(9, 'Crafts')
            , ROW(10, 'Sports'), ROW(11, 'History'), ROW(12, 'Tech')
        ) as tpc(TopicID, TopicName)
    ), cteArticles as (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (VALUES ROW(1, 'A brief history of golf', '2020-01-14')
            , ROW(2, 'Stop action pickleball photos', '2023-06-10')
            , ROW(3, 'The physics of artistic photographs', '2022-07-15')
            , ROW(4, 'Songs of War and Peace', '2022-09-21')
            , ROW(5, 'Writing tech reviews', '2020-05-05')
        ) as art(ArticleID, ArticleTitle, PublishDate)
    ), cteArticleTags as (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (VALUES ROW(1, 11), ROW(1, 10)
            , ROW(2, 7), ROW(2, 10)
            , ROW(3, 6), ROW(3, 1), ROW(3, 7)
            , ROW(4, 2), ROW(4, 4)
            , ROW(5, 12), ROW(5, 7), ROW(5, 4)
        ) as attr(ArticleID, TopicID)
    ), cteUserInterests as (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (VALUES ROW(1, 2), ROW(1, 7), ROW(1, 10)
            , ROW(2, 5), ROW(2, 10)
            , ROW(3, 5), ROW(3, 6), ROW(3, 12)
        ) as attr(UserID, TopicID)
    )/*END of sample data
    Now build solution, look for the set of articles that match for each user*/
    , cteMatch as (
        SELECT DISTINCT U.UserID, A.ArticleID 
        FROM cteUserInterests as U 
            INNER JOIN cteArticleTags as T on U.TopicID = T.TopicID 
            INNER JOIN cteArticles as A on A.ArticleID = T.ArticleID 
    )
    SELECT M.UserID, A.*
    FROM cteMatch as M INNER JOIN cteArticles as A on A.ArticleID = M.ArticleID 
    ORDER BY M.UserID, A.PublishDate DESC
```

BTW, the output of this is as follows

| UserID | ArticleID | ArticleTitle | PublishDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Stop action pickleball photos | 2023-06-10 |
| 1 | 4 | Songs of War and Peace | 2022-09-21 |
| 1 | 3 | The physics of artistic photographs | 2022-07-15 |
| 1 | 5 | Writing tech reviews | 2020-05-05 |
| 1 | 1 | A brief history of golf | 2020-01-14 |
| 2 | 2 | Stop action pickleball photos | 2023-06-10 |
| 2 | 1 | A brief history of golf | 2020-01-14 |
| 3 | 3 | The physics of artistic photographs | 2022-07-15 |
| 3 | 5 | Writing tech reviews | 2020-05-05 |

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're doing. I'm not sure what the correct syntax is in MySQL to SELECT X as (query), and then immediately treat X like a table in a second query. I may just post another question with my exact case, which is a little more complicated.

Comment: @Cmaso, you didn't tag your question as MySQL, so I answered in T-SQL, but this requires only minor syntax adjustment to work in MySQL. I'm editing this to run in MySQL, please test again. Note that the 3 differences are the required `ROW` for each row in the `VALUES` block, the use of /**/ instead of -- for comments, and the `CONVERT` function (which I just removed)

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I've tried running your SQL in HeidiSQL exactly as you typed, and it tells me there's a syntax error. Is it actually supposed to start with "with cteTopics as"?

Comment: @Cmaso That's weird, I pasted it exactly as posted here in an online MySQL and it ran perfectly, yes it starts with "with cteTopics as", the line above is just a comment. the link is https://extendsclass.com/mysql/825408f to where I ran it.

Comment: That is weird - I see it runs fine at your link location. It may be because I'm using an older version of MySQL (5.5)...yes, that was it. I have one DB that runs 5.5 and one that runs 8.0. Runs fine with MySQL 8.0.

Comment: So @Cmaso it runs, does it give the results you asked for? It would help to mark it so if it does as others may find this question in the future and want to know if this works - your help making Stack Overflow more helpful to future seekers is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the 3 most recent articles, in descending date order, that belong to the Travel and Sports topics

This reads like relational division.

As a starter, the following query gives you the ids of all articles that have both topics:

```
select l.article_id
from link_articles_topics l
inner join topics t on t.topic_id = l.topic_id
where t.topic_name in ('Travel', 'Sports')
group by l.article_id
having count(*) = 2
```

With this information at hand, we can bring the corresponding articles and sort them (assuming a column like `article_date`, which is not showing in your sample data):

```
select a.*
from articles a
inner join (
    select l.article_id
    from link_articles_topics l
    inner join topics t on t.topic_id = l.topic_id
    where t.topic_name in ('Travel', 'Sports')
    group by l.article_id
    having count(*) = 2
) l on l.article_id = a.article_id
order by a.article_date desc
limit 3
```

You did not tag your database; this syntax is quite portable should run on most databases - apart from `limit`, which is somehow vendor-specific, and that you might need to adapt.