# SQL to find common elements in multiple lists/resultsets

Tags: sql, mysql

Reference to my previous question, [SQL to find a common element in 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76567375/sql-to-find-a-common-element-in-2-lists).

So I have a website where articles (called "issues") are posted regularly. Issues can belong to one or more counties, to one or more cities, and to one or more topics (called "categories"). Users specify in their account settings which one or more counties, cities, and categories they want to follow, and from this the user's issues are pulled. So the logic to get a given user's issues is to get the 15 most recent issues that belong to at least one of the user's chosen cities or counties, AND that belong to at least one of user's chosen categories.

Fortunately, the DB is set up with mapping tables for all of this. I'll show a simple representation of the tables and columns below:

```
tUsers
User_ID

tIssues
issue_ID    Date

tCounties
County_ID

tCities
City_ID

tCategories
Category_ID

Link_issue_category
Issue_ID    Category_ID

Link_issue_county
Issue_ID    County_ID

Link_issue_city
Issue_ID     City_ID

Link_user_category
user_id     Category_ID

Link_user_county
user_id     County_ID

Link_user_city
user_id     City_ID
```

So with all of these tables, for a given user, I want to get the 15 most recent issues where at least one of the issue's associated cities or counties match at least one of the user's chosen cities or counties, AND at least one of the issue's associated categories match at least one of the user's selected categories.

I'm not sure if this can be done efficiently in a single query, but I run into similar situations from time to time and it would be useful to permanently get my head around how to handle them (in MySQL, specifically). Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query for this can get a bit complex, but you can do it in a single query. The key here is joining and subquerying properly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tIssues.issue_ID,
    tIssues.Date
FROM
    tIssues

-- Join with issue to category link table
LEFT JOIN Link_issue_category ON tIssues.issue_ID = Link_issue_category.Issue_ID
-- Join with issue to county link table
LEFT JOIN Link_issue_county ON tIssues.issue_ID = Link_issue_county.Issue_ID
-- Join with issue to city link table
LEFT JOIN Link_issue_city ON tIssues.issue_ID = Link_issue_city.Issue_ID

WHERE
    -- Filtering issues which belong to user's counties or cities
    (
        Link_issue_county.County_ID IN (
            SELECT County_ID
            FROM Link_user_county
            WHERE user_id = YOUR_USER_ID
        )
        OR
        Link_issue_city.City_ID IN (
            SELECT City_ID
            FROM Link_user_city
            WHERE user_id = YOUR_USER_ID
        )
    )
    -- Filtering issues which belong to user's categories
    AND Link_issue_category.Category_ID IN (
        SELECT Category_ID
        FROM Link_user_category
        WHERE user_id = YOUR_USER_ID
    )

-- Ordering by date to get the most recent issues
ORDER BY
    tIssues.Date DESC

-- Limiting to 15 results
LIMIT 15;
```

Just put the ID number of the person you're looking up information for in place of `YOUR_USER_ID` in the query and let me know if this works. Hopefully the code comments help clarify what's going on.

### Update

The example query I posted does a lot of work and wasn't very optimized. Based on your comment that an issue can belong to only one city and one county but can belong to multiple categories, you could optimize the query.

If you really wanted to eliminate the subqueries in the WHERE clause, you could use joins for user preferences too.

```
SELECT
    tIssues.issue_ID,
    tIssues.Date
FROM
    tIssues

-- Joining issues with county and city link tables
INNER JOIN Link_issue_county ON tIssues.issue_ID = Link_issue_county.Issue_ID
INNER JOIN Link_issue_city ON tIssues.issue_ID = Link_issue_city.Issue_ID
-- Joining with user preferences
INNER JOIN Link_user_county ON Link_issue_county.County_ID = Link_user_county.County_ID
INNER JOIN Link_user_city ON Link_issue_city.City_ID = Link_user_city.City_ID

WHERE
    Link_user_county.user_id = YOUR_USER_ID
    OR Link_user_city.user_id = YOUR_USER_ID

ORDER BY
    tIssues.Date DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

This query uses additional joins to directly connect user preferences to the issues, which removes the need for subqueries within the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. However, the query runs way too long, over a minute even with a date filter. It so happens in my case that an issue can belong to only 1 city and only 1 county, but can belong to multiple categories. So I just ran a query to get Issues based on location, ordered by date desc, then looped over the results in my application language. In the loop, I select count from link_issue_category where issue_ID = issue_ID and category_ID IN (user's list). If count is greater than zero, I add the issue_id to a list, and when that list has 15 elements, break out.

Comment: nice - that's long-running too, unfortunately, maybe because I'm running it in MySQL 5.5 instead of the most recent version. That's okay - mostly, I want to get the concept. I'm thinking "What if I had a website where issues can be related to many things - maybe not just city, county, and category, but also publication, and author - and can be connected to one or more of each? And then I want users to be able to select one or more of each as personal preferences. What's the best way to query the DB to get their issues, based on prefs? And I think you've answered - thanks much.